# How to extract contacts from Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, contacts

A friend of mine just got her GMail account hacked because of a weak password. The attacker still has control of her account. She was using Mail.app to read her emails.

I would like to find a solution to get all the contacts sorted by usage (number of message sent from/to a person), which does not involve typing commands inside a terminal. I have a working solution based on `grep` and `sort` on files found in ~/Library/Mail/V2/... but I don't feel like sending her a script..

Comment: if it helps (doesn't give you the number of messages) you can look at all the previous recipients in Mail.app > Window > Previous Recipients. It lets you sort by last used, email, name, and wether it is in contacts or not.

Comment: @dwightk Thanks I didn't know this window. It may be enough if her contact list is short.

Comment: I assume you already tried gmail recovery ? Mail.app uses the Contacts app.

Comment: @Buscar웃 The informations she gave are being processed. They said it may take several days. The person who took control of her account is most probably actually in Bamako (Mali), and he has tried the standard Western Union scam on her contacts. I hope she will gain access to her account in the near future.

Comment: Actually the password reset is instant by google sending you a automated sms to a phone number or another email that was given during the account creation with instructions.